# About the Turbo Boost Monitor

Tags: windows

I have an Acer laptop and I am getting a message that says the Turbo Boost Technology Monitor 2.0 is faulty - what does this mean?    How will it affect my work and how do I go about rectifying the situation?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? Have you tried googling the error message? What software is showing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the from Intel the latest [version 2.5](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=19105). Since it's only a monitoring app, it doesn't really affect performance (Turbo Boost will still function without it). If you're using Windows 8, the built in Task Manager also show the current CPU frequency.